# awk script works on pure file, but dont work with tail+2

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have my script which gets maximum value of 3 columns of selected file. If file is pure it works good, but if i try to pipe file with tail+2 it just doesnt work anymore. There is code:

```
 BEGIN {max1 = 0; max2 = 0; max3 = 0}
{
if(max1 < $1)
max1 = $1
if(max2 < $2)
max2 = $2
if(max3 < $3)
max3 = $3
}
END {print max1, max2, max3;}
```

i execute code like this : awk -f [codefilename] [targetfile]

works 100% good

i execute code like this (want to remove first line before counting):

awk -f [codefilename] [targetfile] | tail+2

it fails

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: I guess you want: `tail +2 targetfile | awk -f codefilename`

Comment: Thank you it worked! I'm still pretty green on this :D

Comment: if you are used to put the filename at the end, you can do this as well `awk ... <(tail +2 file)`

Comment: nice, will know this for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your example:

```
awk -f codefilename targetfile | tail+2
```

First of all you need a space between `tail` and `+2`. Secondly what is happening is that the output from the `awk` command is piped to tail so its basically like writing:

```
awk -f codefilename targetfile > tmp1
tail +2 tmp1
```

What I guess you want is to take all but the first line from `targetfile` and run your awk code on it, if that's the case you need:

```
tail +2 targetfile | awk -f codefilename
```

Afaik `tail +N` is not supported by all distros, and you would need something like `sed -n '2,$p'` instead. If anyone can clarify, please do.

Comment: Im using SunOS 5.11 so it supports +N just fine :D. Thanks for info again.
p.s yes space between tail and +2 is syntax mistake, my bad.

Comment: And of course you don't need the `tail +2` at all, awk is perfectly capable of skipping lines: `NR>1{...code...}`. @PauliusMickus btw your max calculation is wrong in general - seed with the first value read, don't assume there will be a value greater than zero.

Comment: @Ed Mordon ty ill keep in mind this only works with positive numbers.

Comment: Just change `BEGIN {max1 = 0; max2 = 0; max3 = 0}` to `NR==1{max1 = $1; max2 = $2; max3 = $3}` and it'd work for any numbers (or `NR==2` if you do skip the first line within awk).